# REST Endpoint using MIT and BSD 3-clause license libraries

Tags: mit, bsd

I am making a small side project to make a few dollars. The project basically consists of a couple of RESTful endpoints. My endpoints use various libraries released under MIT and BSD 3-clause licenses, and I was wondering if and how to cite the original authors of the aforementioned so as not to run into problems given the commercial nature of the project.

Example, my endpoints are made in Flask, which is technically released under BSD 3-clause. The same argument applies to Numpy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two licenses that you mention are permissive licenses that are not "internet aware". The main requirements that those licenses have is that

- you do not delete copyright and/or license statements from your source code
- you include a copy of the license text in the documentation that you provide to the recipients of your software (when it is distributed either in source or binary form).

The licenses place absolutely no requirements on you when you provide remote access to the software (over the internet).

If you want to be really nice, you can always mention the used third-party components and their licenses in your published API documentation, but there is no requirement to do so.